# Commit tags to use for changing a Fuchsia OS file?

Tags: gerrit, fuchsia

[Fuchsia > Guides > Contribute changes > Add commit message tags](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/source_code/contribute_changes#add-commit-message-tags) states:

[[image: Add commit message tags]]

(1)How does one determine what tags to use? (2)Is there an algorithm calculating the two strings such as simply using the directory name and `..`? If this were the case, the file path already has that info.

(3)Apparently `[docs]` is in addition to `[parent]` `[component]`. Are their other additional tags?

(4)For example, if changing the file `fuchsia/src/lib/fxl/README.md` what tags should be used?

I found no info in [Gerrit Code Review for Git](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/) about `[tags]`. So, it seems to imply that this is a Fuchsia OS convention or info within a commit message.

[Fuchsia > Gerrit > Repositories > fuchsia > tags](https://fuchsia-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/fuchsia,tags) has an empty list.

[image: Fuchsia > Gerrit > Repositories > fuchsia > tags]

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse the git tags with the tags mentioned in the Fuchsia documentation.
You are required to add `[parent][component]`, what they call tags, to your commit messages.

My guess that your commit message would look something like:

```
[lib][fxl] Updating README.md
```

You can look at the history of your component for inspiration: https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+log/refs/heads/master/src/lib/fxl

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am confused. I am looking for more info than 'and more'. Where do you find this '[parent][component]' described?

Comment: In the link you provided: https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/source_code/contribute_changes#add-commit-message-tags